# XML parser displays blank for URLs which has no style in Android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, rss, rss-reader

Currently I have implemented a simple RSS reader for Android following the tutorial from:

http://techiedreams.com/android-simple-rss-reader/

The rss feed's URL is something like: h--p://test....../rss.xml

But for some rss URL, when accessed through browser in desktop it shows "his XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it."

For such URLs, the app could not parse the data and it just shows a blank page.

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

That blank page is probably just that - blank. Message "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." is just a warning not error about feed doesn't have styles (these styles are only used to display feed in some sort of form which user can read but XML is intended for data not for users to read raw XML) and if XML is properly formed you should see it in your browser and you should be able to parse it with you app. The problem could be that XML isn't showing at all and that is the reason why you don't see anything in browser and in app. Example of RSS where this message is shown but you still get content [example rss with warning](http://www.b92.net/info/rss/novo.xml). I don't think you can resolve this. You can just try to find other RSS feeds that have that information that you want to collect.